# Error while displaying webpage in IE

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website, but there is an issue when i run it on IE.
There are two tabs with data. In IE, when i switch to other tab, it shows some space below the page, perhaps because the first tab contains more data as compared to the other.
In other browsers the page refreshes and adjusts itself, but in IE its not working fine.

Login to the page;
http://demo.datasoft.ca/Remityourway/RYWLogin.aspx

with, 
USERNAME:karim.amin@datasoft.com.pk
PASSWORD: 123

Go to MANAGE ACCOUNTS > PAYEE,

there are two tabs Swift Details and Payee Details, you can click on Payee Details to see the issue.


Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not clicking on a random link from an unknown website. Could you provide more details, or replicate the problem on a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

Re: freefaller: I will click it, I'm fearless!

It looks like the problem is caused by your code:

```
<a id="accoundBalance" href="javascript:panelSwiftVisible()" class="tabbtn">Swift Details</a>
```

The function `panelSwiftvisible()` seems to set the visibility, which will effect the other elements of the page.  Instead, change your function to setting the element:

```
display: none;
```

instead of:

```
visibility: invisible;
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: it is already Display:none; 
but Visibility: invisible; doesn't work either.

Comment: The problem is caused because one of those `div`s is not being hidden properly.  If it was truly set to `display:none;` then it wouldn't leave that blank space at the bottom.  Try clicking `f12` in IE and use the pointer to select the blank space at the bottom to see what `div` is not being hidden properly.